# keep element always visible while moving it up and down

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to keep `titleact` always visible while moving it up and down, but sometimes it goes outside of parent's borders.

I don't want to scroll parent each time a button is clicked but only if `titleact` is near to the top/bottom border.

Any help?

```js
$('.title').on('click', function() {
  $('.titleact').removeClass('titleact');
  $(this).addClass('titleact');
});

$('.btnup').click(function() {
  let obj = $('.titleact');
  let i = obj.index('.title');
  if (i == 0) {
    return;
  }
  let targ = $('.title').eq(i - 1);
  obj.insertBefore(targ);

  let parent = obj.parent();
  if (obj.offset().top <= parent.offset().top) {
    parent.animate({
      scrollTop: parent.scrollTop() - parent.height() - obj.position().top
    });
  }
});

$('.btndown').click(function() {
  let obj = $('.titleact');
  let i = obj.index('.title');
  let count = $('.title').length;
  if (i == count - 1) {
    return;
  }
  let targ = $('.title').eq(i + 1);
  obj.insertAfter(targ);

  let parent = obj.parent();
  let h1 = obj.outerHeight(true);
  if (obj.offset().top + h1 >= parent.offset().top + parent.height()) {
    parent.animate({
      scrollTop: parent.scrollTop() + parent.height() - h1
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid lightseagreen;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.title {
  padding: 2px 0;
  margin: 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.titleact {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent' id='parent'>
  <div class='title titleact'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class='btnup'>UP</button>
<button class='btndown'>DOWN</button>
```

Comment: It seems to be working pretty well for me in Chrome. Under what circumstances do you see a problem?

Comment: @DavidHammond, pls, click on button `DOWN` until `titleact` is a last child. Then start clicking on button`UP`, and you'll see - `titleact` is not visible on first scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your original script and made some changes that I think do what you want. A few things to note:

- Moving the element seemed to affect the scroll in some cases, so I have it restore the original scrollTop immediately after moving the element.
- The new scroll position is calculated by finding the difference in position between the titleact element and the first element in the list.

```js
$('.title').on('click', function() {
  $('.titleact').removeClass('titleact');
  $(this).addClass('titleact');
});

$('.btnup').click(function() {
  let obj = $('.titleact');
  let i = obj.index('.title');
  if (i == 0) {
    return;
  }
  let parent = obj.parent();
  let origScrollTop = parent.scrollTop();
  let targ = $('.title').eq(i - 1);
  targ.before(obj)
  parent.scrollTop(origScrollTop);

  if (obj.offset().top < parent.offset().top) {
    let first = parent.find(":first");
    parent.animate({
      scrollTop: obj.position().top - first.position().top - parent.height() + obj.outerHeight(true)
    });
  }
});

$('.btndown').click(function() {
  let obj = $('.titleact');
  let i = obj.index('.title');
  let count = $('.title').length;
  if (i == count - 1) {
    return;
  }
  let parent = obj.parent();
  let origScrollTop = parent.scrollTop();
  let targ = $('.title').eq(i + 1);
  targ.after(obj)
  parent.scrollTop(origScrollTop);

  if (obj.offset().top + obj.outerHeight(true) > parent.offset().top + parent.height()) {
    let first = parent.find(":first");
    parent.animate({
      scrollTop: obj.position().top - first.position().top
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid lightseagreen;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.title {
  padding: 2px 0;
  margin: 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.titleact {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent' id='parent'>
  <div class='title titleact'>lorem ipsum 1</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 2</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 3</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 4</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 5</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 6</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 7</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 8</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 9</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 10</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 11</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 12</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 13</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 14</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum 15</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class='btnup'>UP</button>
<button class='btndown'>DOWN</button>
```

Comment: almost perfectly. sometimes `titleact` is not scrolled to the top but on the middle on parent. Could you try, pls

Comment: @blueSky, see my new changes.