# Why is position().top showing 8 on an element without any margin or padding?

Tags: jquery

Why is console result of this code `8`? I'm expecting `0`, because there is not any margin, padding etc. between `.title` and `.parent`.

```js
console.log($('#title').position().top);
```

```css
.parent {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 79px;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  line-height: 54px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='title' id='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there is a `margin` added to the `body` by default in most browsers. You will need to remove that:

```js
console.log($('#title').position().top);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 79px;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  line-height: 54px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='title' id='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

I would suggest you use a reset stylesheet to standardise the starting point in every browser for all your CSS.

> But position is relative to parent, not to body!

Almost - it's related to the *offset parent* (see the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/position/)). A minor but crucial difference. That means the closest parent element which is not `position: static` as they all are by default. As you don't have any of those, it goes up to the `body`. To fix this, set `position: relative` on the `.parent`:

```js
console.log($('#title').position().top);
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 79px;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  line-height: 54px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='title' id='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but `position` is relative to parent, not to body!

Comment: It's relative to the offset parent - I edited the answer to explain that too.

Comment: thanks Rory, in fact I'm trying to solve this - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225022/`, could you help with this, pls?